# Proving: (G,*) is a group. For all $a,b\in G $, if $a*b=b*a$ then $a^{-1}*b^{-1} = b^{-1}*a^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove the theorem below. Is my proof correct?

**Theorem:** Suppose (G,*) is a group. For all $a,b\in G $, if $a*b=b*a$ then $a^{-1}*b^{-1} = b^{-1}*a^{-1}$.

**Proof:** Assume (G,*) is a group, $a,b\in G $, and $a*b=b*a$.

Then,

$a*b=b*a$

Multiplying both sides by the inverse,

$(a*b)^{-1}=(b*a)^{-1}$

Since G is Abelian, $(a*b)^{-1}$= ${b}^{-1}*{a}^{-1}$, so

${b}^{-1}*{a}^{-1}$ = ${a}^{-1}*{b}^{-1}$

Therefore,

${a}^{-1}*{b}^{-1}$ = ${b}^{-1}*{a}^{-1}$.

I am bit confused by my second step which takes the inverse on both sides. It seems like this proof is correct. I don't see any other way of proving that $a^{-1}*b^{-1} = b^{-1}*a^{-1}$ without directly starting from $a*b=b*a$.

Comment: I think your proof is correct.

Comment: Inverses are unique.  You can also show the two products you mention are inverses of the same element: $a*b=b*a$.

Comment: I'm confused.  If $a*b = b*a$ for all $a,b \in G$ and $G$ is a group then $a^{-1}, b^{-1} \in G$.  So the property states $a^{-1}*b^{-1} = b^{-1}*a^{-1}$.  The fact that $a^{-1},b^{-1}$ are particular inverses is totally irrelevant.  They commute just like any other elements would commute. This proof seems .... weird.

Comment: I think maybe the theorem you want to prove is that if $a,b \in G$ and $a*b=b*a$ for *those* two element but *not* necessarily for *any* two elements then $a^{-1}*b^{-1} =b^{-1}*a^{-1}$.  That is not so trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case we have for two given $a,b\in G$ that $ab=ba$, then preoperating by $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ and postoperating by $a^{-1}b^{-1}$, we have,

$$b^{-1}a^{-1}aba^{-1}b^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}baa^{-1}b^{-1}$$

and the desired result follows by using associativity and $xx^{-1}=x^{-1}x=e_G~\forall~x\in G$ where $e_G$ denotes the group identity.

If you want a more direct proof, just note that $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab=e_G$ using $ab=ba$ and by rearranging the equation, the result follows.

---

[The answer below assumed that the entired group $G$ is abelian]

I think it's simpler to think like this:

Let $a,b\in G$ which is abelian, i.e, $ab=ba~\forall~a,b\in G$

Then, denote $x:=a^{-1}$ and $y:=b^{-1}$. Since $G$ is a group, every element $a\in G$ has an element $a^{-1}\in G$, i.e., inverse exists in the group for every element of the group.

So, $x,y\in G$ and since $G$ is abelian, $xy=yx$ which is equivalent to $a^{-1}b^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}~\forall~a,b\in G$ as desired.

---

tl;dr: Basically, substitute $a\mapsto a^{-1}$ and $b\mapsto b^{-1}$ in the commutative property of abelian groups, i.e, $ab=ba$ (the substitution is valid since inverses exist for each element of the group in the group, i.e., $G$ is closed under inversion).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Substitution is easier.

Comment: Oh right, I thought earlier that the problem stated $ab=ba~\forall~a,b\in G$ which would mean $G$ is abelian. If we simply have for two given $a,b\in G$ that $ab=ba$, then the desired result simply follows by preoperating with $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ and postoperating by $a^{-1}b^{-1}$. Let me add that in my answer.

Comment: I see, the assumption that G is abelian might be wrong. I understand the revised proof, thanks for pointing out the mistake in my assumption that G was abelian.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have basically got it...  though you may have an unnecessary step in there:  it's the famous "substitution principle"...  You can substitute any group elements for  $a $ and $b $...

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is abelian then $a^{-1}b^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$ by definition.  THere is nothing to prove.

I think maybe the theorem you want to prove is that if $G$ is *not* necessarrily abelian, but $a$ and $b$ are two elements that happen so that $a*b = b*a$, then prove $a^{-1}b^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$ That is not so trivial.

$(a*b)*(b^{-1}*a^{-1}) = a*(b*b^{-1})*a^{-1} = a*e*a^{-1} = a*a^{-1} = e$. so $(a*b)^{-1} = b^{-1}*a^{-1}$.

$(a*b)*(a^{-1}*b^{-1}) = (b*a)*(a^{-1}*b^{-1}) = b(a*a^{-1})*b^{-1} = b*e* b^{-1} = b*b^{-1} = e$.  So $(a*b)^{-1} = a^{-1}*b^{-1}$.

As inverses are distinct, $b^{-1}*a^{-1}=a^{-1}*b^{-1} = (a*b)^{-1}$.

Comment: By the hypothesis, $a*b=b*a$ with the group operation, isn't that equivalent to stating G is abelian?

Comment: @Axion004, I think the problem seeks for the more general case that for two given $a,b\in G$ which commute, their inverses also commute (which doesn't require the entire group $G$ to be abelian). See the edits in my answer.

Comment: @Axion004 For example, in $S_6$, the elements $a = (1 ~ 2 ~ 3)$ and $b = (4 ~ 5 ~ 6)$ commute (they satisfy $ab = ba$) even though the overall group isn't abelian.  And lo and behold, the inverses $a^{-1} = (1 ~ 3 ~ 2)$ and $b^{-1} = (4 ~ 6 ~ 5)$ also commute as predicted by this result.

Comment: I see, I think my assumption that G is abelian is wrong. I understand both of the proofs presented.

Comment: It's a reasonable interpretation and interpretation to assume the hypothesis is stating the group is abelian.  But that would be a rather trivial problem as $c*d = d*c$ for all elements so it will be true for $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$  by definition.  There'd be utterly no reason to ask such  question that I have to assume that the proof is to show it is true for whenever $a*b=b*a$ whether or not the group is abelian.

Comment: Oh.... The theorem is *VERY* badly worded.  Note it says "for all $a, b \in G$, ***IF*** $a*b=b*a$ then....".  See the after than "for all" there is a conditional "if".  So it's not true that all $a*b=b*a$ but for all the $a,b$ where it *IS* true then....  If it were me, I'd state it as "For any $a,b$ where...."  I think that'd be clearer.  No point saying "for all" clause if you will restrict it *later*.  And where vs if makes it clearly it is a non-universal condition.

Answer (score 0):

Like others, I do not think this was your assignment.  Since $G$ is abelian, proving that $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ commute is trivial and a silly exercise:  they are elements in an abelian group.

The more likely intention was:

**Claim:** If $a$ and $b$ are commuting elements in $G$ then their inverses also commute.

The proof is easy:  from $ab =ba$ we have $(ab)^{-1} = (ba)^{-1}$ and so $b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$.